# How to create pipeline with Jenkins and Azure Release?

Tags: azure-devops, jenkins-pipeline, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-releases

I am having a Jenkins which takes care of build process which publishes docker image to `Azure Container Registry`, post which I would like to deploy them to `Azure Kubernetes Service`.

For that, I am planning to use `Azure Release`, however I am feeling that Azure Release component is poorly written without YAML Support unlike `Azure Pipeline` which seems more user friendly. Is `Azure Release` not mature enough ?

I tried to work with Azure Pipeline, however Azure Pipeline expects the source to Source Code, whereas I expect it to start after the docker image is build.
Is my approach correct am I missing something ?

Is this correct approach ?

Comment: Release pipelines are *older* than YAML pipelines by several years. You can create a YAML [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#define-a-containers-resource) that runs when a container is published to a container registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using FluxCD and Jenkins. Azure Release doesn't go hand in hand with Jenkins and ends up with lot more issues such as,

SourceCode isn't aware of what current release is, In Jenkins and FluxCD combo we can make sure source code is aware of the currently deployment by auto committing the version to the source code, this can't be done in Azure Pipeline as it just another CD without any access to Source Code.